# Choosing Inductor for dc-dc converter USB-C Application

Tags: dc-dc-converter, inductor, usb-c

I am a high school student working on building a USB-C charger using TPS25740B(93 W) ([datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps25740b.pdf)) as the PD controller and MC34167 ([datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/MC34167_D-2315411.pdf)) as the dc-dc converter. I am a little confused as to how to determine the minimum inductance value.

From my understanding, the PDOs available are 5V@3A, 9V@3A, 15V@3A, and 20V@4.65A(93W Max/20V)

Partial Schematic:

[image]

These are the design equations given by the MC34167 datasheet.

[image]

Here is where I am getting a little confused:
[image]

If I understand correctly, that means that I<sub>PK(switch)</sub> cannot be higher than 5.5A (Minimum Current Limit Threshold mentioned earlier in datasheet), and the lower inductance, the higher the ripple, so therefore I need to find the biggest ripple allowed.

Also, even though I am not using this equation, is the datasheet supposed to say I<sub>L</sub> = .2(I<sub>L avg</sub>) instead of 2(I<sub>L avg</sub>)?

Setting I<sub>PK(switch)</sub> to 5.5A, where I<sub>L</sub> is Peak to Peak ripple current:

5.5=I<sub>L avg</sub>+(I<sub>L</sub>/2)
5.5=I<sub>out</sub>+(I<sub>L</sub>/2)

5.5-I<sub>out</sub>=I<sub>L</sub>/2

(5.5-I<sub>out</sub>)*2=I<sub>L</sub>

Now I can plug into the equation for L(and therefore t<sub>on</sub> and I<sub>L</sub>):

V<sub>in</sub>=40

V<sub>sat</sub>=1.5 (given by datasheet)

V<sub>F</sub>=.7 (given by datasheet of diode I will be using)

F<sub>osc</sub>=72000 (given by datasheet)

For 5V@3A:

V<sub>out</sub>=5

I<sub>out</sub>=3

Calculated L=13.53uH

For 9V@3A:

V<sub>out</sub>=9

I<sub>out</sub>=3

Calculated L=20.27uH

For 15V@3A:

V<sub>out</sub>=15

I<sub>out</sub>=3

Calculated L=26.14uH

For 20V@4.65A:

V<sub>out</sub>=20

I<sub>out</sub>=4.65

Calculated L=79.81uH

So in order to satisfy all these PDOs, I need an inductor over 79.81 uH?

Also, any feedback on the post/formatting would be appreciated.

Comment: A link to the data sheet AND a schematic would help a lot.

Comment: @Andyaka TPS25740B:[link](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps25740b.pdf), MC34167:[link](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/MC34167_D-2315411.pdf), I am using the same schematic as figure 19(with different R1 values depending on the PDO), and a different inductor.

Comment: And different V_in and (V_out and I_out) depending on the pdo

Comment: Post a schematic; people reading stuff can be lazy and , of course there's no ambiguity if you post it. Please ensure you mark up where values are not the same.

Comment: @Andyaka added schematic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I calculate the inductor values for the two extremes 5 V and 20 V, I have the following results considering a 40% ripple current:

[image]

If you now look at the ripple current in the inductor depending on the selected voltage, you have the following data:

[image]

Now, as you know, losses in the inductor will split between iron or core losses and copper losses. If you look at core losses, they depend on the \$\Delta B\$ swing, the associated hysteresis and temperature: simply put, the more ripple you have, the higher the core losses. 40% ripple selection for operating a buck converter is a typical choice nowadays considering the good magnetic materials we have access to. Years ago, in the Unitrode manuals, it was recommended around 10% of the average current. This is no longer the case.

Because the buck converter is assumed to operate in continuous conduction case or CCM in all of your configurations, the duty ratio will remain the same at a given operating point, regardless of the inductor value. Therefore, going for the lowest inductor value selected for a 40% ripple at 5 V will induce close to 60% ripple at a 20-V output. On the other hand, selecting the highest value obtained for a 40% ripple at 20 V will reduced this ripple to 30% or so at 5 V. If you consider core losses as part of the core selection - and it should be - then perhaps limiting the ripple to 40% worst case is the argument to defend. Now, you can also look at other parameters like \$LI^2\$, volume, dc and ac resistance etc. which play a role also for the final selection. Keep in mind that cost (and availability these days) in the end also enters the picture.

Finally, I would recommend you to take a look at my free simulation platforms that I described [here](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) and will let you simulate all these scenarios easily with the demo version of SIMPLIS. Below are typical shots you can get in a few seconds of simulation time:

[image]

This is with 74 µH and a 20-V output. The macro automates the compensation strategy and it gives good crossover and phase margin. And if you now reduce the inductance to 50 µH, the ripple increases as expected:

[image]

Please note that for the same average current (\$I_{out}\$ = 5 A), the peak current is higher with the lower inductance as expected: \$I_p=I_{out}+\frac{\Delta I_L}{2}\$ so depending on the max current limit of your controller, it may also affect the final process selection. Good luck with this exercise!

Ps: for good engineering writing practice, please use the lower-cased terms dc-dc and ac-dc and not DC/DC (or AC/DC) in which the "/" means or.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The datasheet seems to have the ripple current as  200%(it says IL can be 2*Iout), which confused me because I thought it would be somewhere between 20%-40%. Also, Would this inductor work ok: HCTI-120-6.7([datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/643/ds-st-high-current-torodial-inductors-series-1661536.pdf))? It is 120 uF, 6.7A max, and 40 milliohms max resistance. Also since I will be having two charging ports, I thought it would be neccessary for the inductor to be shielded to prevent interference(this one is). Thanks again!

Comment: You can operate the buck in different ways and a 200% ripple simply means the buck operates in boundary mode: when the inductor current hits 0 A at turn off, then a new cycle starts. The frequency is varying with line and load conditions but you can potentially obtain quasi zero voltage switching on the power switch which is good for the loss budget. Your inductor looks fine with me as it is given for a dc current of 6.7 A and gives plenty of margin as \$I_{sat}\$ is slightly higher. Look at \$L\$ versus temperature as well.